# Can a server detect it when I use a userscript to change the innerHTML of an element?

Tags: javascript, server, userscripts

I made a userscript to change the look of an element at page-load to trick my friends. Can the server detect that I am changing the DOM on my end?

I know just a tiny bit of web dev and google resulted in conflicting answers so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: Generally speaking, no.  Once the server has 'served' the page requested (HTML) it does not know what it is done to it (i.e. changes to the DOM) on the client side.

Comment: "*Can the server detect that I am changing the DOM on my end?*" What exactly are you changing that you believe the server would even care...?

Answer (score 2):

`Usescript` is on top of `Javascript`, and therefor is run on the local browser, that code will not run on the server, so there is nothing to detect.

But server side validation for the data that is submitted can stop you from doing certain things

Comment: Sorry for the late response, By data that is submitted do you mean data submitted by me? In which case I don't think there is any since I am not giving any input.

Comment: JS can be use to alter a form submission data for example. I was providing a more generic answer for other people in the future

Answer (score 1):

A typical HTTP server generally would not be directly able to detect such manipulation on its own, since there is no facility in bare-bones HTTP for the client (your browser) to relay information to the server once the server begins or closes its response to the initial request.

It would be trivial, however, for the front-end JavaScript the server responds with to be configured to alert the server of unexpected changes to the DOM as the result of a userscript (or similar).

Comment: The DOM that is being modfied by userscripts is a local copy, nothing the server can detect there.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Right... which is the point I'm making in my answer. You seem to believe your statement is at odds with my answer, can you clarify more specifically where you believe we aren't saying the same thing?

Comment: well you just edited your answer as soon as I made my comment ;-)

Comment: also it could be possible that the tampering of local JS removes the logic that alerts the server of any tampering.

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez Yes, agreed, but that is outside the scope of the question. The answer here is "yes", and I've explained why that it is *possible*.

Comment: your initial answer was misleading, thanks for editing to make it better